# Check if element in mongodb collection c# - very beginning

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using c# and mongodb and I am a beginner in both.
I am using  MongoDB.Driver.Builders
But I don't get Query class which is mentioned here:
http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.6/html/b02d4be3-7e01-332f-a051-3647a72adfea.htm

What I have to import?

My task is to check if JSON object already exists in my mongo DB.
And multiple examples of this are using Query class

Or, how can I do it?

Comment: Look at the docs: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/

Answer (score 0):

You should reference these two:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver.Builders;
```

Then you can do something like

```
var entities = Database.GetCollection<Entity>("entities")
```

and use regular LINQ to check whether the object you are looking for exists.

Comment: Does mongo C# driver 2.0 support linq? I thought not

Comment: @user3669608 That's correct; LINQ support returns to the C# driver in 2.1.